# Repeating record using for loop in database

Tags: python, django

in this code am trying to add the student record in the attendance database whenever the student image is captured by the webcam so **name = image name stored** adding that the image name is the same as the studentid stored in Student entity, whenever the detected face name exist in **Name = the list of images name** then it will add the student info to the attendance database.

The code just works fine but it keeps repeating the records how can I limit it to add the record just once and not repeating it.

```
    def markattendance(name):
        for n in Names:
            if name in Names:
                # print(name, "Exist")

                # fitches the information related to the detected name
                attend = Student.objects.filter(student_id=name).values('student_id', 'student_fname', 'student_lname','fk_course_id_id')
                #print(attend)

                # filter returns a queryset. A queryset isn't a single object, it's a group of objects so it doesn't make sense
                # to call save() on a queryset. Instead you save each individual object IN the queryset:
                for object in attend:
                    #print(object)
                    if object.get('student_id') not in attend:
                        # INSERT SQL statement behind the scenes. Django doesn’t hit the database until you explicitly call save().
                        reg = Attendance(student_id=object.get('student_id'),
                                         student_fname=object.get('student_fname'),
                                         student_lname=object.get('student_lname'),
                                         course_id=object.get('fk_course_id_id'))
                        # print(reg)
                        reg.save()
                    else:
                        pass
```

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

I'll try to answer with my understanding of your code (which may not be perfect, correct me if I'm mistaken).

First, your `for` loop at the start is useless, you don't use even once the `n` variable you introduce there. That's probably from where the problem is coming from, as you're executing again and again the same code.

Now, your `attend` queryset probably contains one `Student` instance as you're filtering by id, which I guess is unique among all Students. You then shouldn't be looping over each of its elements, as there's only one.

Finally, your line `if object.get('student_id') not in attend:` will always return `False`. You're getting the value of `student_id` of the unique element in your queryset, then looking if your queryset contains this same value.

But your queryset contains `Student` instances, not `id`s so it won't return `True`.

This, added to the fact that you're looping over these few lines of code, will result in you getting multiple records.

You probably need something like that (based on what I understood) :

```
def markattendance(name):
    if name in Names:
        attend = Student.objects.filter(student_id=name).values('student_id', 'student_fname', 'student_lname','fk_course_id_id')
        student_with_name = attend[0]
        reg = Attendance(student_id=object.get('student_id'),
                         student_fname=object.get('student_fname'),
                         student_lname=object.get('student_lname'),
                         course_id=object.get('fk_course_id_id'))
        reg.save()
```

Comment: Am really thankful for your time and effort, the way you wrote is way better just in `student_id=object.get('student_id')` i placed `student_with_name` instead of `object`. however, the attendance still got repeated :(

Comment: I didn't understand what you wanted to achieve with your ```if object.get('student_id') not in attend:``` so I could only try, please explain what you want to verify in order for me to understand how I can help you. Because `attend` here only contains the instance of Student with the `name` so I don't understand what you want to verify.

Comment: I wanted to verify if a student record has been added or not to the list to prevent repeating the record, am sorry if i explained it poorly. yet I managed to do it using if statement `if Attendance.objects.filter(student_id=name).exists():
                print("student exist")
            else:
                reg = Attendance(student_id=student_id=object.get('student_id'))
                print("student added")
                reg.save()`

Comment: From what I understood, you're always getting the value of the Student with the `name` you defined earlier, so you will always get this Student in your Queryset, and only this student. If you want to verify that this student isn't in any `Attendance` record you should make a query on your `Attendance` model instead of `Student`. Something like `attendance_of_student = Attendance.objects.filter(student_id=name).exists()` with maybe a verification of the course or of the time, whatever you need.

Comment: Didn't see your if statement before, that seems good to me, does that work ?

Comment: yes the if statement solved the repeating issue